# Is there a Japanese version of urbandictionary?

Tags: slang, resources, onomatopoeia

I came across this phrase today:

> むぎゅむぎゅ

From context, it looks like it should mean something like "cute" or "poor you", but I couldn't find it on jisho.org or goo.ne.jp.

Is there a Japanese equivalent of urbandictionary, somewhere I can look when standard dictionaries fail?

Thanks!

**Edit:** Removed mention of かわいそう, as it was a distraction from the question.

Comment: かわいい and かわいそう are usually thought of closer to antonyms than synonyms.

Comment: @BillyNair I think he used 「そう」when he probably meant「らしい」

Comment: Most likely right @Chris. And as for the actual question: I used to have a link to maybe the best Onomatopoeia site, it was black with reddish orange letters, maybe the most complete one I've ever seen, but can not find it!! The link was on my old computer that died... If anyone finds that one post it here, please!! (ps. this is a close second: http://bit.ly/NDBDOW)

Comment: @Chris Reading your comment, now I see what the OP was at. Until then, the relevant part in the question did not make any sense to me.

Comment: @BillyNair They are totally different. Not even antonyms. What I think is that an antonym for かわいい is 憎らしい, and an antonym for かわいそう is perhaps 相応 (not sure on this part).

Comment: Thank you @sawa, that is why I phrased it "Closer to...", rather than get into a big discussion about the actual meanings of each word since that wasn't the main focus of the question and rather speculation on the part of the OP. The example running through my head was new Japanese speakers calling someone's baby かわいそう, not the opposite meaning but the opposite intention.

Comment: OP here! Interesting theories, but I actually thought from context it was _either_ "cute" (可愛い) or "poor you!" (かわいそう) - I wasn't suggesting they were synonyms. I can see how my phrasing was confusing though. :)

Comment: Based on the answer from Chris (with extra info provided by Sawa), this looks to be one of the hundreds of onomatopoeia that the Japanese language has. A friend of mine has spent a few years researching and cataloguing them, I don't know if he's ever released his research though.

Comment: @JamieTaylor - you should ask him! I'd certainly bookmark it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not Japanese, but as far as I know 「むぎゅむぎゅ」depicts squeezing something softly probably more than once as Sawa pointed out. I think you can use it in relation to some texture that has elasticity. The context it is used in can be cute, but is not limited to it. For instance, you see 「むぎゅむぎゅ」used to describe how the dough of a bagel feels. However, it is probably most common to use it when talking about skin or fat. Humorously, you can find some videos of cats on YouTube with descriptions containing 「むぎゅむぎゅ」.

I'm not sure why, but I wasn't able to find it in a dictionary to my surprise. However, I know of two dictionaries that might be able to help which have entries for onomatopoeia or 擬音語.

Those are [Nihon Jiten](http://www.nihonjiten.com/nihongo/giongo/index.html) and [Zokugo-dict](http://zokugo-dict.com/).

Comment: +1, but I would say squeezing rather than grabbing. The repetition of むぎゅ expresses repeated action. It is not just once.

Comment: I have the JED dictionary (http://bit.ly/NrKBDc) on my phone, it came up with ムギュウ - Squeezing, hug, hugging.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, and for the dictionary recommendations - I'll add them to my list of tools.

The "hug" meaning makes sense in context - person A wants to return home, person B comments on their status, I guess expressing that they want to hug person A! (むぎゅむぎゅ)

Cheers.